# Cert 401 Analytic Snapshot question

Tags: certification, dev401

A second Cert 401 question from me today - As I will be sitting the exam tomorrow. Just did a mock exam and passed every other question except this one and I am a little bit confused.

What will cause the analytic snapshots run to fail? Please select three (3) choices.

A. The source report has been deleted

B. The target object has a trigger on it

C. The running user has been inactivated

D. The target object is a custom object

E. The source report is saved as matrix report

The suggested answer is A B C. While A and C are definitely correct. I am a little confused with B and E. The source report should be either tabular or summary in my opinion and the analytic snapshot will have a issue with target object trigger only when the trigger is an insert trigger. Am I right about this?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: I don't trust those mock exams available on the internet. I have identified many wrong answers on them and will end up confusing you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems a bit confusing to me as well.  I was under the impression that you couldnt have a summary or matrix report as the source report.

From the Help pages

> *Source report must be tabular*.
>
> The report in the Source Report field is no longer in tabular format. Choose a new source report or update the existing source report's format to tabular.

So you may have found an error with this mock exam.  This is not surprising as none of the mock exams are NOT actually supported by SF.  Quite the contrary actually, SF tries to shut them down as they come across them.  I would use the mock exams with caution as there is no guarantee they are correct.

You seem to be correct around B as well.  An insert trigger on the object will cause failure as well

> *Target object must not include an insert trigger.*
>
> An Apex trigger runs
>   when new records are created for the custom object in the Target
>   Object field. Remove the Apex trigger or choose a target object for
>   which an Apex trigger does not run when new records are created.

See help pages here  https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=data_troubleshooting_snapshots.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Yep, the trigger part is correct, I just ran into this.   Insert trigger makes the "analytic snapshot" job fail.   Update trigger is OK though.

Answer (score 0):

Actually B is correct.  And whoever said that about matrix and summary reports is wrong.  It actually must be a summary or matrix report.

btw, this is how I discovered it...  I created a field called OwnerID on the object Analytic snapshot.  Since tasks cannot have lookup fields on them, it is impossible for them to be owned in an analytic snapshot.  To get around this, I thought that I could write a basic trigger that said upon insert and upon update, owerid__c = OwnerID and I was wrong.  When doing it, I got the following error.

Target object must not include an insert trigger.

I am hoping that it allows me to have an update trigger where I can come behind it and populate the owner field with the new owner.  Fingers crossed...

btw good luck with the test.  I am working on my 501 certification now.  I have a lot to learn before I take it, but I think that I am about halfway there.

Comment: Update triggers do not break the snapshot job.  Only the insert triggers are a problem.